# Can you use Arrays as keys in Dictionaries?

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I initially had a list of strings that I thought would be unique, so I built a dictionary and used that list of strings as values.
Example: `[contact1,contact2,contact3]`

However, I realized that the strings are not unique, but the combination of 2 strings is.
Example: `[[contact1,contact1],[contact1,contact2],[contact2,contact2]...]

So since I have 2 unique objects, that I'd like to use as Dictionary keys, can I use Arrays of Strings as Dictionary keys?

Assuming I cannot, if my strings will not contain commas, I suppose I could merge them and separate with commas. Bad idea?

Comment: Did you try it? Trying first would be much better than posting a question.

Comment: If you tried it, then you should know whether it works or not. And if you know, why post the question? I'm really trying to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
let x = [["a1", "a2"]:"1", ["b1", "b2"]:"2"]
println("x: \(x)")

let v = x[["a1", "a2"]] as String
println("v: \(v)")
```

Output:

```
x: {
        (
        b1,
        b2
    ) = 2;
        (
        a1,
        a2
    ) = 1;
}

v: 1
```

Comment: Check the type on `x`: because of Objective-C bridging, that gives you an `NSDictionary`, not a Swift `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any `Hashable` type as a dictionary key -- Swift's built-in `Array` type isn't hashable, but since `NSObject` is, and Swift arrays bridge silently to Objective-C arrays, you can inadvertently use `NSArray` as a key.

Comment: Yes, correct but: "so what?" There is really no such thing as "Pure Swift", at least not yet, the basic Foundation classes are still necessary, really basic classes like NSData. The Swift team built this bridging into the Swift language so I see no reason not to use it. I shouldn't need to care about the internal implementation details.

Comment: They're different types, and one should be precise about what we're working with. I'm not saying it's inappropriate to use Foundation classes, but using them without realizing that's what you're doing could set you up for trouble down the road.

Comment: Swift hides that detail by design so it is an implementation detail. One could say the same thing about bridging to CFString or any of the several underlaying concrete classes in a class cluster. As for "trouble down the road", Apple should warn in there documentation about the automatic bringing—but they don't. Perhaps it is an issue of String not being  complete that is is not a hashable type.  My suggestion if one does not want to have two string classes is to use Objective-C.

Comment: It's not really just an implementation detail - when you're using an `NSDictionary` you forego all of Swift's type safety checks. Again, that's fine if that's what you want, but you're signing yourself up to have to cast out of `AnyObject` every time you access something in the dictionary. That's why the `as String` is necessary in your code, and it will crash if you're ever wrong.

Comment: Sounds like Swift is not really ready if it will **silently** bridge to an environment that will crash! But Swift does not safety check array bounds other than crashing and Xcode suggests fixing Optionals by adding a "!", explicit unwrapping which tosses safety checking. So it seems the argument is not to use Swift—at least yet.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible.

You can use string like `contact1_contact1,contact1_contact2,contact2_contact2`